# How to create method in Notepad ++ to auto-reset XML value="1" when it is always changed back to value="0"

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, notepad++

So I am currently working on the Duck Creek configuration system and we set two values in one of our xml files to value="1" in order to enable a toolbar we use that makes tracing back duck creek fields that generate an error easier. When our code is deployed at the end of our sprints, our dev machines get updated with the latest production code and the two xml values are reverted back to value="0" and we have to manually edit it each time.

Is there any way this process can be automated using notepad ++ so that when our dev machines get updated from the production machine, the value remains value="1" or automatically changes back to value="1"? I've attached pictures of the xml file we manually edit in notepad++ and highlighted the two fields that I would like to always have set to "1" even when our dev system is updated with the production system code. Also, we don't set the value to "1" in our production system, so our customers can't have access to the dev toolbar when they use our system. I'm very sorry if this is a ridiculous question, but I am new to this job and trying to be productive, I'm sure I'm asking a ridiculous question here.

[image]

Comment: I suppose you could use a macro inside N++ (search&replace). But a Powershell script might be a better option though.

Comment: @E.Wiest any pointers on how I can get this done with a powershell script? I'm very new to coding so I'm not entirely sure how to do this?

Comment: OK. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Powershell you can go with :

```
# Load the file
$File = Get-Content ".\Web.config"
$XML = [XML]$File

# XPath expression
$XPpath = "//add[starts-with(@key,'Show')]"

# Selecting the nodes
$nodes = $XML.SelectNodes($XPpath)

# Updating the attribute value for the selected nodes (set it to "1")
$nodes | % { $_.SetAttribute("value", "1") }

# Settings for the output file (keep indent and no xml declaration)
$xwSettings = new-object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$xwSettings.indent = $true
$xwSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = $true;

# Create an XmlWriter and save the modified XML document
$xmlWriter = [Xml.XmlWriter]::Create(".\Web.config", $xwSettings)
$XML.Save($xmlWriter)
```

Save the preceding code as `fixweb.ps1`.
Place the script in the folder where `Web.config` lies (or edit the path in the script).
Then right click on it > "Execute with Powershell". Accept the warning ("Y"). Then, check the result.

If you don't want to accept the warning each time (assuming the Powershell execution policy is setted up to restricted), you can create a .bat file. It will be used to launch the script (i.e.: bypass Powershell execution policy). [Source](https://stackoverrun.com/fr/q/11798003#42898542)

Content of the .bat (`launch.bat`) :

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -windowstyle hidden -noninteractive -nologo -file "fixweb.ps1"
```

Before :
[image: Bef]

After :
[image: Aft]

Side note : The XPath expression used in the script to select the nodes should be hardened. Since I don't know exactly the content of your "Web.config", some errors could occur (more values replaced than the two targeted nodes).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is just what I was looking for!